# When is the word metric on a finitely generated group right-invariant?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group with finite generator $S$, and define the metric $ d_S : G \times G \to \mathbb{Z} \cap [0, \infty)$ by
$$d_S(x, y) = \min \left\{ \ell \geq 0 : \exists s_1, \ldots, s_\ell \in \left( S \cup S^{-1} \right) \setminus \left\{ e \right\} \; \left( x^{-1} y = s_1 \cdots s_\ell \right) \right\} ,$$
i.e. $d_S$ is the word metric associated to $S$. The metric $d$ will automatically be left-invariant, i.e. $d_S(x, y) = d_S(gx, gy)$ for all $g, x, y \in G$, since $(g x)^{-1} (g y) = x^{-1} g^{-1} g y = x^{-1} y$.

However, this metric need not always be right-invariant. For an example of the word metric not being right-invariant, consider the example of $G = F_2$, i.e. the free group on two generators, with (free) generator $S = \{a, b\}$. Then $d_S(e, b) = 1$, but $d_S(e a, b a) = d_S \left( e, a^{-1} b a \right) = 3$, so the "canonical" word metric on the free group with two generators is not right-invariant.

On the other hand, if $G$ is abelian, then every word metric is right-invariant. Right-invariance is equivalent to the conjugation action $g \cdot x = g^{-1} x g$ of $G$ on itself satisfying $d_S(e, g \cdot x) = d_S(e, x)$ for all $g, x \in G$, since $d_S (xg , y g) = d\left(e, g^{-1} y g \right)$. So conjugation needs to preserve word length, and of course the conjugation action for an abelian group is trivial. Alternatively, if $G$ is finite, and $S = G$, then $d_S$ is the discrete metric (i.e. $d_S(x, y) = \delta(x, y)$), and thus is also right-invariant. This trick works for any discrete group if we drop our assumption that $S$ be finite, but I'd rather consider the finite generator case.

My question: is there a straightforward characterization of when the word metric is both left- and right-invariant? My guess would be that *every* word metric is right-invariant if and only if $G$ is abelian, but I can't prove this either. This seems like the kind of problem that should be elementary to solve, but alas, I haven't solved it.

Alternatively, is there some sense in which the word metric will be "almost right-invariant", where we can place bounds on the extent to which the word metric fails to be right-invariant?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT 1: Here's a partial answer based on @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez's suggestion, at the end of which are some related follow-up questions.

> **Claim:** Let $S$ be a finite generator for $G$, and set $\tilde{S} = \left(S \cup S^{-1} \right) \setminus \{e\}$. Let $g \star x = g^{-1} x g$ be the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation (note: this is a right action which I foolishly wrote on the left; thanks @Captain Lama for pointing this out). Then $d_S$ is right-invariant if and only if $s \star t \in \tilde{S}$ for all $s, t \in \tilde{S}$.

**Proof:** The necessity is obvious, since if there existed $s, t \in \tilde{S}$ for which $s \star t \not \in \tilde{S}$, then we'd have $d_S(s, t s) = d_S \left( e, s \star t \right) \neq 1 = d_S (e, t)$. Now we claim it's sufficient.

First, we remark that if $\tilde{S}$ is closed under conjugation by itself, then $\tilde{S}$ is closed under conjugation by all elements of $G$, i.e. $g \cdot s \in \tilde{S}$ for all $s \in \tilde{S}, g \in G$. This follows by writing an arbitrary element $g$ of $G$ as a product of elements of $\tilde{S}$ and applying an inductive argument. Moreover, we remark that if $\tilde{S}$ is closed under conjugation, then $|x \star y| \leq |y|$ for all $x, y \in G$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes word length. Let $x = s_1 \cdots s_\ell, y = t_1 \cdots t_m$, where $s_i, t_j \in \tilde{S}$ and $|y| = m$. Then
\begin{align*}
|x \star y| & = |x \star (t_1 \cdots t_m)| \\
& = |(x \star t_1) \cdots (x \star t_m)| \\
& = \left| t_1' \right| \cdots \left| t_m' \right| \\
& = m & = |y| ,
\end{align*}
where $t_j' = x \star t_j \in \tilde{S}$.

Thus conjugation cannot increase word length. We claim, however, that conjugation *preserves* word length, i.e. that $|x \star y| = |y|$ for all $x, y \in G$. Assume for contradiction that there exist $x, y \in G$ such that $|x \star y| < |y|$. Let $y' = x \star y$. Then $\left| x^{-1} \star y' \right| = |y| > \left|y'\right|$. This contradicts our earlier claim that $\left|z \star w\right| \leq |w|$ for all $z, w \in G$.

Thus if $\tilde{S}$ is closed under conjugation, then conjugation preserves word length. From here, it follows that if $x, y, g \in G$, then
$$d_S(x g, y g) = \left| (x g)^{-1} (yg) \right| = \left| g^{-1} x^{-1} y g \right| = \left| g \star \left( x^{-1} y \right) \right| = \left| x^{-1} y \right| = d_S(x, y) .$$
This concludes the proof.

This criterion encompasses some non-abelian groups. For example, as we mentioned, every finite group can be realized in this way by taking $S = G \setminus \{e\}$.

This proof can be elaborate on to show the word metric is "almost right-invariant" in the sense of ["Lie Groups and Error Analysis"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.8784&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Schiff and Shnider: Set
$$M = \max_{s, t \in \tilde{S}} |s \star t| \in \mathbb{N} .$$ For each $g \in G$, set $\rho(g) = M^{|g|}$. Consider $x, y \in G$, and let $g = s_1 \cdots s_\ell, x^{-1} y = t_1 \cdots t_m$ for $s_i t_j \in \tilde{S}$, where $\ell = |g|, m = \left| x^{-1} y \right| = d_S(x, y)$. Then
\begin{align*}
d_S(x g, y g) & = \left| g \star \left( x^{-1} y \right) \right| \\
 & = \left| (g \star t_1) \cdots (g \star t_m) \right| \\
 & \leq |g \star t_1| + \cdots + |g \star t_m| \\
 & = \sum_{j = 1}^m |(s_1 \cdots s_\ell) \cdot t_j| .
\end{align*}
Applying an inductive argument, we can conclude that $|(s_1 \cdots s_\ell) \cdot t_j| \leq M^\ell$ for all $j$, so
\begin{align*}
d_S(x g, y g) & \leq \sum_{j = 1}^m |(s_1 \cdots s_\ell) \cdot t_j| \\
 & \leq \sum_{j = 1}^m M^\ell \\
 & = M^\ell \cdot m \\
 & = M^{|g|} \left| x^{-1} y \right| & = M^{|g|} d_S(x, y) .
\end{align*}

Edit 2: As @Sean Eberhard pointed out, this estimate can be cleaned up significantly to get
\begin{align*}
d_S(x g, y g) & = \left| g^{-1} \left( x^{-1} y \right) g \right| \\
 & \leq \left| g^{-1} \right| + d_S(x, y) + |g| \\
 & = 2|g| + d_S(x, y) \\
 & \leq (2|g| + 1) d_S(x, y) ,
\end{align*}
so in general $d_S(x g, y g) \leq (2|g| + 1) d_S(x, y)$. However, this is estimate is in general sharp. Consider the case where $G$ is a free group of rank $\geq 2$ generated freely by $S$. If $g \in G$, then we can write $g = s_1 \cdots s_\ell$ for $s_1, \ldots, s_\ell \in S \cup S^{-1}$, where the word is in reduced form so $|g| = \ell$. Let $x$ be an element of $S \cup S^{-1}$ such that $x \not \in \left\{ s_1, s_1^{-1} \right\}$. Then $g^{-1} x g = s_\ell^{-1} \cdots s_1^{-1} x s_1 \cdots s_\ell$, and this is the reduced form, so $\left| g^{-1} x g \right| = 2|g| + 1$. Thus
$$d_S(g, xg) = 2|g| + 1 = (2|g| + 1) |x| = (2|g| + 1) d_S(e, x) .$$
So if $G$ is a nonabelian free group and $S$ is a free generator for $G$, then for every $g \in G$ exists $x \in G$ such that $d_S(g, xg) = (2|g| + 1) d(e, x)$, meaning that $2|g| + 1$ is the optimal Lipschitz constant for $x \mapsto g^{-1} x g$.

Assuming all the above is correct, I think there are at least two questions that are reasonable to ask:

- What groups admit right-invariant word metrics, or equivalently, which groups *admit* finite generators closed under conjugation? Clearly every finitely generated abelian group fits this bill, but I've yet to cook up an infinite non-abeliean example
- For which groups is *every* word metric right-invariant? Clearly every finitely generated abelian group fits this bill, but I've yet to cook up a non-abelian example, including the finite case.

Comment: Suppose the symmetric generating set S does not contain e and is such that d is biinvariant. If s, t are in the set S, then d(s,ts) = d(e,t) = 1, so there was exists a u in S such that s^{-1}ts = u. This implies, since S generates the group, that the set S is closed under conjugation. This is also a sufficient condition for what you want, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez It's necessary, yes, but I'm not sure if it's sufficient. This would make sure that conjugation sends words of length $1$ to each other, and that conjugation is non-expansive since $| g \cdot ( s_1 \cdots s_\ell ) | = | (g \cdot s_1) \cdots (g \cdot s_\ell) | \leq |g \cdot s_1| + \cdots + |g \cdot s_\ell| = \ell$, but I'm worried that conjugating might introduce additional cancelations that cause $|g \cdot w| < |w|$, where $|\cdot|$ is word length.

Comment: Just a remark, the conjugation action you define is not a left but a right action (it does not change anything to the statement).

Comment: @CaptainLama Good catch! I had already written my original post before it occurred to me to check whether the action was on the left or right, and I decided it wasn’t worth checking, since it wouldn’t make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mariano [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4644088/when-is-the-word-metric-on-a-finitely-generated-group-right-invariant/4644188#comment9803882_4644088) in the comments, the metric is right-invariant if and only if $S$ is conjugation-invariant.

Answers to your follow-up questions:

1. Which finitely generated groups have a finite symmetric conjugation-invariant generating set?

Suppose $S$ is a finite symmetric conjugation-invariant generating set for $G$. The conjugation action of $G$ on $S$ induces a homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Sym}(S)$ whose kernel has index at most $|S|!$. But the kernel is $Z(G)$. Therefore $G$ has a finite-index (and finitely generated) center.

Conversely, suppose $Z(G)$ has finite index in $G$. Then all conjugacy classes are finite (they have order at most the index of $Z(G)$). Let $S$ be a finite symmetric generating set for $G$. Then $S' = \bigcup_{g \in G} S^g$ is a finite symmetric conjugation-invariant generating set.

There are plenty of uninteresting examples like $G \times \mathbf{Z}^d$ for any finite group $G$.
A nonsplit example is given by the nontrivial semidirect product $C_3 \rtimes \mathbf{Z}$ (which is nonsplit as an extension of its center).
It is possible to classify all examples in terms of data consisting of a finite group $G$ and some outer automorphisms of $G$.

2. Which finitely generated groups have the property that *all* finite symmetric generating sets are conjugation-invariant?

One nonabelian example is the quaternion group $Q_8 = \{\pm1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$, whose conjugacy classes are $1, -1, \{\pm i\}, \{\pm j\}, \{ \pm k\}$. Therefore every set of the form $\{x, x^{-1}\}$ is conjugation-invariant, so every symmetric generating set is conjugation-invariant.

Conversely suppose $G$ has a conjugacy class $C$ not of the form $\{x\}$ or $\{x, x^{-1}\}$. Let $S$ be a finite symmetric generating set for $G$. If $S$ is not conjugation-invariant, we are done. Otherwise $S \cap C$ is either $\emptyset$ or $C$. If $S \cap C = \emptyset$ then pick $x \in C$ and consider instead $S' = S \cup \{x, x^{-1}\}$: this finite symmetric generating set contains only part of $C$ so it is not conjugation-invariant. Suppose on the other hand that $C \subseteq S$. Let $x \in C$. Since $S$ generates $G$ there must be some $s \in S$ such that $x^s \notin \{x, x^{-1}\}$. Note moreover that $s \ne x^{\pm1}$. Let $S' = S \setminus \{x, x^{-1}\}$. Then $s, x^s \in S'$, so $x = (x^s)^{s^{-1}} \in \langle S'\rangle$, so $S'$ still generates $G$. Again it contains only part of $C$, so it is not conjugation-invariant.

Therefore we want to classify finitely generated groups such that all conjugacy classes have the form $\{x\}$ or $\{x, x^{-1}\}$. Note that any subgroup of such a group is automatically normal: such a group is called a [Dedekind group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group), and they are known to be either abelian or of the form $Q_8 \times B \times D$ where $B$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group and $D$ is a torsion abelian group with all elements of odd order. But if $x \in D$ is nontrivial then $\{(\pm i,1,x)\}$ is a nontrivial conjugacy class of $Q_8 \times B \times D$ not of the required form, so $D$ must be trivial. Specializing to the finitely generated case, it follows that $G$ is either abelian or of the form $Q_8 \times B$ where $B$ is a finite elementary abelian $2$-group.

Comment: Thanks! This might be more involved, or too broad to admit a useful answer, but since right-multiplication will always be bi-Lipschitz, a kind of “almost right-invariance,” do you know of any way to classify the groups where the Lipschitz constant satisfies some growth condition? That is, where we can control how far from right-invariant we are? The exponential bound I found sounds pretty ugly, though perhaps optimal for something like a free group. If it’s not clear, I’m very much a novice in this area.

Comment: @AJY The Lipschitz constant is never worse than $1 + 2|g|$. Since $d(x, y) = |x^{-1} y|$ we have $d(xg, yg) = |g^{-1} x^{-1} y g| \le |x^{-1}y| + 2|g|$. If $x \ne y$ then $|x^{-1} y| \ge 1$ and we get $d(xg, yg) \le (1 + 2|g|) d(x, y)$.

Comment: yeah, I realized after writing that comment that my constant was grossly oversized

Comment: Properly speaking, this is rather: if and only if $S\cup S^{-1}$ is conjugation-invariant. Note that the existence of such a generating subset means that $G$ is a FC-group (i.e. all conjugacy classes are finite), and for a f.g. group this is the same as having center of finite index.